# arraylist anidados java jsp

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

tengo 2 arraylist que los traigo desde un servlet cursos y usuarios, tengo que hacer un dos  anidadosen arraylist cursos trae los cursos de un profesor y el arraylist usuarios trae los emails de los padres, este es el codigo que yo arme pero no se como realizar los  anidados para que cuando seleccione un curso se muetren los datos de ese curso.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Cursos"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Usuarios"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
 <title>Insert title here</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form action="ServletsNuevaNotificacionDocente" method="post" id="curso">
 <label>Nota</label>  <textarea name="textarea" rows="10" cols="50">Nota</textarea> 
 <br>
 <label for="archivo"> archivo:</label>
 <input type="file" name="archivo" id="archivo">
 <% ArrayList<Cursos> cursos = (ArrayList<Cursos>) request.getAttribute("cursos");  %>
 <% ArrayList<Usuarios> usuarios = (ArrayList<Usuarios>) request.getAttribute("usuarios");  %>
 <select name="curso" id="curso">
    
        <%  for (Cursos cur : cursos) {%>
 <option value="<%=cur.getNumerocurso()%>"> <%=cur.getAño()+cur.getDivision()%></option>
         <%
        }
        
                %>

 </select>  
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block"   type="submit" >Enviar Notificacion </button>

 </form>



 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118896/discussion-on-question-by-jose-piccoli-arraylist-anidados-java-jsp).

Answer (score 0):

según tus comentarios al parecer quieres capturar el evento de cambio de opcion de un select y su valor; luego enviarlo a un ajax...

seria de esta forma:

```
addEventHandler(document, 'DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    // evento en el Select 1
    addEventHandler(document.getElementById('el_id_del_select'), 'change', function() {
        window.toAjax(this.value);
    });
});

function toAjax($valor){
// documentado en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery
 var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 //esta seria tu URL para el Servidor/Funcion en el servidor java
 xhReq.open("GET", "sumGet.phtml?valor="+$valor, false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var serverResponse = xhReq.responseText;
 alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15" // Esta es la famosa respuesta del servidor aqui debe recibir el select 2 armado o los datos para ser armado

}
```